# Problems using different login credentials to connect to DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

We've recently implemented DocuSign electronic signature functionality into our application. Testing completed successfully and we're able to dispatch documents for signature request using our own DocuSign login / account credentials. One our clients however has reported that they are unable to complete this task using their own login credentials. I have verified that they have entered their DocuSign account details correctly. The $authenticationApi->login call completes successfully but the request to create an envelope fails with the following response:

[401] Error connecting to the API (https://eu.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/11968233/envelopes)

"One or both of Username and Password are invalid."

Any help as to the source of the issue appreciated.

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After performing the login call, you'll need to record the base URL for the individual's account, and then make subsequent calls against that endpoint. If they're not on the EU environment, eu.docusign.net would be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this is the issue. The $authenticationApi->login call returns a docusignConfig object. The object includes host URL which I assume is the base URL that you are referring to. When I use both my own and the client's login credentials the host URL is the same - https://eu.docusign.net/restapi. Also, the docusignConfig object is passed in its entirety when attempting to create the envelope object, so if the URL was different then this would be reflected in the docusignConfig object. Any further ideas?

Comment: Upon further investigation what you suggested was right after all. The host hadn't been set correctly. Thanks!